# read textfile in pyspark2

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-2.2

I am trying to read a text file in spark 2.3 using python,but I get this error.
This is the format textFile is in:

```
name marks
amar 100
babul 70
ram 98
krish 45
```

Code:

```python
df=spark.read.option("header","true")\
    .option("delimiter"," ")\
    .option("inferSchema","true")\
    .schema(
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("Name",StringType()),
                StructField("marks",IntegerType())
            ]
        )
    )\
    .text("file:/home/maria_dev/prac.txt")
```

Error:

> ```
> java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Text data source only
> produces a single data column named "value"
> ```

While I am trying to read a textFile into an RDD, its being collected as a single column.

Should the data file should be changed or shoud I change my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of [**.text**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.text)(produces only single value column) use `.csv` to load file into DF.

```
>>> df=spark.read.option("header","true")\
    .option("delimiter"," ")\
    .option("inferSchema","true")\
    .schema(
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("Name",StringType()),
                StructField("marks",IntegerType())
            ]
        )
    )\
    .csv('file:///home/maria_dev/prac.txt') 

>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> df
DataFrame[Name: string, marks: int]
>>> df.show(10,False)
+-----+-----+
|Name |marks|
+-----+-----+
|amar |100  |
|babul|70   |
|ram  |98   |
|krish|45   |
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for the info on .csv, but the problem is in the textFile there are no commas used, as mentioned above the code section. It is a just a textfile with spaces differentiating column values and newLine for rows.

Comment: @abhishekanand, As we are using **delimiter as " "(space)** option while loading the csv file, so df dataframe will load the data from the csv file **with space delimiter**. Then you are going to have **Name,marks columns** in the df.